# Magic link for playing random video from youtube playlist

Tags: youtube

Here is one magic link, everytime you click it you will get a new guided meditation with Gurudev!

[aoliv.in/meditatewithgurudev](http://aoliv.in/meditatewithgurudev)

Can anyone tell, how this is happening ? Is there any tool to create such link ?

> What I observed is, random video is getting played from same playlist.

Comment: Check the soource code - `view-source:https://artofliving.app/whatsapp/youtube.php`. I believe the page has the playlist and it randoms selects a index from the playlist and builds the URL (*or somehow gets the URL of the video - linking back the playlistid, video_id and index*).

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes yes it happening there, index and video_id is changing, but still not able to figure how its happening. 
Thank you, It's helpful.